# Remove duplicate rows for multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have over 100 dataframes (`df1, df2, df3, ....`) each contains the same variables. I want to loop through all of them and remove duplicates by `id`. For `df1`, I can do:

```
df1 <- df1[!duplicated(df1$id), ]
```

How can I do this in an efficient way?

Comment: Put them in a list and then use `lapply`. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) will be helpful. My answer there gives an easy way to get a named list and gregor's excellent answer illustrates methods for working with lists of data.frames.

Comment: If they are all data frames with object name starting with "df" you might want to create a list using `ls(pattern = "df[0-9]")` and then cycle over them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're dealing with 100 similarly-structured data.frames, I suggest instead of naming them uniquely, you put them in a list.

Assuming they are all named `df` and a number, then you can easily assign them to a list with something like:

```
df_varnames <- ls()[ grep("^df[0-9]+$", ls()) ]
```

or, as @MatteoCastagna suggested in a comment:

```
df_varnames <- ls(pattern = "^df[0-9]+$")
```

(which is both faster and cleaner). Then:

```
dflist <- sapply(df_varnames, get, simplify = FALSE)
```

And from here, your question is simply:

```
dflist2 <- lapply(dflist, function(z) z[!duplicated(z$id),])
```

If you must deal with them as individual data.frames (again, discouraged, almost always slows down processing while not adding any functionality), you can try a hack like this (using `df_varnames` from above):

```
for (dfname in df_varnames) {
  df <- get(dfname)
  assign(dfname, df[! duplicated(df$id), ])
}
```

I cringe when I consider using this, but I admit I may not understand your workflow.

Comment: Is there a way to do this *between* data frames? That is, to remove duplicates not only within each of the data frame, but find and eliminate duplicates that might exist across data frames (without merging the data frames)?

Comment: Most likely, yes ... I suggest opening a question with reproducible data, as I doubt I could do it justice in a comment. @johnjohn

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78244243/remove-duplicated-rows-within-and-between-data-frames-stored-in-a-list