# Remove duplicated rows within and between data frames stored in a list

Tags: r, list, duplicates, lapply

A list of data frames:

```
my_list <- list(structure(list("_uuid" = c("xxxyz", 
                                      "xxxyz", "zzuio", "iiopz"), country = c("USA", 
                                                                              "USA", "Canada", "Switzerland")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)), 
                structure(list("_uuid" = c("xxxyz", "ppuip", 
                                      "zzuio"), country = c("USA", "Canada", "Canada")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                             -3L)))
my_list
[[1]]
  _uuid     country
1 xxxyz         USA
2 xxxyz         USA
3 zzuio      Canada
4 iiopz Switzerland

[[2]]
  _uuid country
1 xxxyz     USA
2 ppuip  Canada
3 zzuio  Canada
```

I want to remove duplicated rows both within and between the data frames stored in that list.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163966/remove-duplicate-rows-for-multiple-dataframes) works to remove duplicates within each data frame:

```
my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(z) z[!duplicated(z[["_uuid"]]),])
my_list
[[1]]
  _uuid     country
1 xxxyz         USA
3 zzuio      Canada
4 iiopz Switzerland

[[2]]
  _uuid country
1 xxxyz     USA
2 ppuip  Canada
3 zzuio  Canada
```

But there are still duplicates between data frames. I want to remove them all, with the following desired output:

```
[[1]]
 _uuid   country
 iiopz   Switzerland

 [[2]]
 _uuid   country
 xxxyz   USA
 zzuio   Canada
 ppuip   Canada
```

Notes:

1. I want to eliminate duplicates on `_uuid` (other variables can be duplicated)
2. I need a solution where it is not needed to merge the data frames before checking for duplicates
3. If possible, I wish to retain the last observation. For example, in the desired output above, "zzuio  Canada" existed in both df, but was kept in the last df only, that is, df 2.
4. I have more than 100 dfs, with variable names that don't necessarily match between dfs. That said, the id is always called "_uuid"
5. I need to reassign the result to the same object (in the case above, `my_list`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shot, starting with a reduction and then `Map`-applying it to the original list of frames.

```r
previous_ids <- rev(Reduce(
  function(prev, this) unique(c(prev, this$id)),
  rev(my_list), init = character(0), accumulate = TRUE))[-1]
previous_ids
# [[1]]
# [1] "xxxyz" "ppuip" "zzuio"
# [[2]]
# character(0)
```

This gives us the ids from frames further in `my_list` that we need to remove "here". We interpret this to mean that for the last frame, we have no IDs we need to remove from other frames; in the first frame, we have 3 ids that are seen later in the list, so they need to be removed from "this" (first) frame. (Side note: perhaps the name `previous_ids` is a misnomer ...)

With this, we can do simply:

```r
Map(my_list, previous_ids,
    f = function(dat, rmid) {
      dat[!duplicated(dat$id, fromLast = TRUE) & !dat$id %in% rmid,]
    })
# [[1]]
# [1] id      country
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# [[2]]
#      id country
# 1 xxxyz     USA
# 2 ppuip  Canada
# 3 zzuio  Canada
```

Using your updated data, this still works. The only thing is since your ID field is non-standard (starting with a `_`, R does not like that), we need to either use backticks `` dat$`_uuid` `` or use `[[` `dat[["_uuid"]]`.

```r
previous_ids <- rev(Reduce(
  function(prev, this) unique(c(prev, this[["_uuid"]])),
  rev(my_list), init = character(0), accumulate = TRUE))[-1]
previous_ids

Map(my_list, previous_ids,
    f = function(dat, rmid) {
      dat[!duplicated(dat[["_uuid"]], fromLast = TRUE) & !dat[["_uuid"]] %in% rmid,]
    })
# [[1]]
#   _uuid     country
# 4 iiopz Switzerland
# [[2]]
#   _uuid country
# 1 xxxyz     USA
# 2 ppuip  Canada
# 3 zzuio  Canada
```

Comment: It works, but there is a further issue with my id name, which is `_uuid`. I completely edited my question, adding also an observation so that df1 doesn't end up empty. Can you please review?

Comment: Okay, how does that change things? Change from `dat$id` to `dat$\`_uuid\`` and it works the same with your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

We could add a temporary column `".rm"` (for remove), created from unlisting the `"id"` column and scanning it for `rev` `duplicated`. This gives a vector that can be `split`ted along `rep`eated consecutive integers each `nrow` times for each sub-list and added to the sub-lists using `` `[<-`() ``. Finally we `subset` for not `TRUE`s in `".rm"` and remove that temporary column.

```
> fn <- \(x, idcol) {
+   Map(`[<-`, x, '.rm', value=
+         lapply(x, `[[`, idcol) |> 
+         unlist() |> 
+         rev() |> 
+         duplicated() |> 
+         rev() |> 
+         split(
+           sapply(x, nrow) |> {
+             \(.) mapply(rep.int, seq_along(.), .) |> unlist()
+           }()
+         )
+   ) |> 
+     lapply(subset, !.rm, select=-.rm)
+ }
> fn(my_list, '_uuid')
[[1]]
  _uuid     country
4 iiopz Switzerland

[[2]]
  _uuid country
1 xxxyz     USA
2 ppuip  Canada
3 zzuio  Canada
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(my_list)
list(structure(list(`_uuid` = c("xxxyz", "xxxyz", "zzuio", "iiopz"
), country = c("USA", "USA", "Canada", "Switzerland")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(`_uuid` = c("xxxyz", "ppuip", "zzuio"), 
    country = c("USA", "Canada", "Canada")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```

Comment: Many thanks. On my 'real' list, this triggers the following error message: "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], value = dots[[3L]][[1L]]) : 
  replacement has 70512 rows, data has 159
In addition: There were 41 warnings (use warnings() to see them)". Any idea why?
Also, I prefer to keep last because these are more recent in time in my real data (i.e., have more accurate information). But no worries if that is not possible.

Comment: @johnjohn Maybe you overlooked to replace something. I have wrapped it in a function to make it easier to use.

Comment: @johnjohn Last observation of xxxyz is also in second sublist, so first sublist would be empty if we'd use last observation, right?

Comment: thanks @jay.sf (a) I also would prefer to keep "zzuio" in second sub-list (please see my desired output in question). (b) The current code still produces exactly the same error. By any chance, could this be due to the fact that me id column is called "_uuid"? I noticed that initial underscore causes issues for other operations.

Comment: Crossing messages. What I would want is this: keeping into account all duplicates, I want to keep the last one, and assign it to the df where it occurs. Say a duplicate appears in df1, df2, and df3. It should be eliminated from df1 and df2, but appear in df3. So yes first list would be empty, EXCEPT, of course, for observations that are not duplicates. I edited my question.